# Reloading function causes onclick handlers to stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

So I have the following

```
<form id="uploadControls">
    <input type="file" id="browseFiles">
    <input type="button" id="startUpload" value="Upload">
    <input type="checkbox" id="overwrite">
</form>
```

And those are used by some javascript to control a file upload mechanism. The backend works perfectly fine. I use resumable.js(https://github.com/23/resumable.js) and here is a small sample snippet of my upload controls

```
var resume;
function resumableUpload(){
    resume = new Resumable({
        url: uploadURL,
        query: {overwrite: !!($("#overwrite").attr('checked'))},
        size: 1024*1024
    });
    // some events with callback functions
    resume.assignBrowse(document.getElementById("browseFiles"));
}
$("#startUpload").live("click",function(){
    resume.upload();
});
```

Now if someone were to check the checkbox to allow the file to overwrite a previous existing one (save without a timestamp), I need to update the `query` parameter in the resumable object, and the only way I was able to do that was with reloading `resumableUpload()` . The problem is, when the call is made by something like this:

```
$("#overwrite").on('click',resumableUpload);
```

Then all the `onclick` handlers stop responding.

I tried the following:

```
$("#overwrite").on('click',function(){
    $("#uploadControls").each(function(){
        this.reset();
    });
    startResumable();
});
```

But that didn't seem to work.

What am I not doing correctly? This worked fine with using the resumable.js library to bind the filepicker to a `<button>` but that didn't work on Firefox, so I need a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using delegation:

```
$("#uploadControls").on('click','#overwrite',function(){...});
```

BTW:

```
$("#startUpload").live("click",function(){...});
```

Should be:

```
$(document).live("click","#startUpload",function(){...});
```

**LIVE** is deprecated:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().